# How to store registration form data in arraylist within android

Tags: android

i am beginner of android and assign a task. how to store the following data in arraylist and show it on another activity as,,,
for example: shafi
             shapo
             password
             24
see the following image and help me as.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQJKW.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the data using intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, Details.class);
intent.putExtra("cost", item.getCost()+"");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in another activity you can get those values using get extra

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("cost");
```

Comment: when i click on register button. the data should save in array list. how can i do it.

Comment: you mean you want to store list of registers in array list

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using shared preferences.
Advantages :
1. You can check whether person already logged in or not.
2. You can retrieve these data at any point of time within the app.
3. You can enable autobackup and include shared preferences that helps you to get same data back when person re installs the app from same account in Google play.
and many more
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent to pass data to other activity:

```
String name,surname, pass, age;

name = edtName.getText().toString();
surname = edtSurname.getText().toString();
pass = edtPass.getText().toString();
age = edtAge.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
intent.putExtra("sname", surname);
intent.putExtra("pass", pass);
intent.putExtra("age", age);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

 and in the mainActivity get like this:

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
 String surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on register button on click listener

```
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    // add elements to the array list
al.add(name, username,password,age);

//passing arraylist from MainActivity to Second Actiivty

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                intent.putExtra("array_list", arr);
                startActivity(intent);
```

for fetching data in Second Activity use this

```
ArrayList<String> fetchList= new ArrayList<String>();
fetchList=  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("array_list");
```